# Question about the proof of the strong maximum principle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The strong maximum principle says that if a function $u$ satisfies the Laplace's equation at the open space $D$ and is continuous at the boundary $\partial{D}$ and achieves its maximum at $\partial{D}$ and at a point of $D$ then the function is a constant.

The proof is the following:

[image]

$x_M$ : the point where the function achieves its maximum

$x_M \in D$

$u(x) \leq u(x_M)=M, \forall x \in D$

$u(x)=u(x_M), \forall \text{ choice of circle } (1)$
$$$$
Could you explain me the relation $(1)$? What does this mean?

Comment: Is this all the information you are given? I am confused about what you mean with "$\forall$ choice of circle"

Comment: @ellya Unfortunately yes.. :/ That's what I'm also confused about..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I get what is going on but it is quite badly worded (though probably by no fault of your own).

A function satisfying laplace's equation $-\Delta u=0$, $x\in D$, is called harmonic.

A property of a harmonic function, is that the mean integral of the function over any sphere (circle) of any radius centred at a point $x_0$ is equivalent to the $u$ evaluated at $x_0$.

I.e. $u(x_0)=(\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dy)/(n\alpha(n)r^{n-1})$ (where $n$ is the dimension and $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the unit $n$-sphere).

Now $u(x)=u(x_M)\,\forall$ choice of circle means that:

$M=u(x_M)=(\int_{\partial B(x_M,r)}u(y)dy)/(n\alpha(n)r^{n-1})\le M$

For this to hold $u$ must be constant in every ball and thus constant everywhere.

Comment: In my notes the strong maximum principle is before the harmonic function. Using the harmonic function is the only way to explain this?

Comment: So to understand the proof:

Does it mean that if it stands that $u(x)=u(x_M)\,\forall$ choice of circle then the function is constant?? Or do we conclude from an other relation that it $u(x)=u(x_M)\,\forall$ choice of circle and so the function is contant??

Comment: I've put in an edit, hopefully it makes things more clear :)

Comment: In my notes, there is the following formula for the mean value that is equal to the value of $u$ at the center of the disc if the function $u$ satisfies the Laplace's equation$$u(0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{u(\overrightarrow{r}')}ds$$
Is this formula equal to the formula that you use:
$$u(x_0)=\frac{\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(y)dy}{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}$$??

Comment: Yes it is, $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the unit sphere in dimension $n$, also we are not restricted to only centereing at $0$ we can centre at any $x_0$ as well :)

Comment: Ok!! So, it is as followed: We take a circle with center at $x_M$
$$M=u(x_M)=\frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{u(\overrightarrow{r}')}ds \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{M}ds=M \frac{1}{2 \pi a}\int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{}ds =M \frac{1}{2 \pi a} 2 \pi a=M $$
The $ \leq $ should be $=$, so $u=M=u(x_M), \forall \text{ choice of circle }$. Is this correct??

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right :)

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much for your help!!! :-)

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Comment: I am looking again at this proof and I have some questions...
$$$$
-From the mean value we have the following when we take a circle with center at $x_M$:
$$u(x_M)=\frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{u(\overrightarrow{r}')}ds$$
Isn't this an integral at the boundary of the disc( $\partial{D}$)??
Is $M$ the maximum only at $D$, or is it the maximum at $\overline{D}$?? 
$$$$
-To calculte the integral $\displaystyle{\int_{|\overrightarrow{r}'|=a}{u(\overrightarrow{r}')}ds}$ do we use the formula of the line integral??

Comment: In general I believe the strong maximum principle states that if $u$ attains its maximum inside $D$, then it is constant, and with regards to the integral, it depends on the dimension I guess, since in $\Bbb R^2$, the boundary of a disk is a circle, so it would be a line integral, whereas in $\Bbb R^3$ the boundary of a sphere is a surface, so it would be a surface integral.

Comment: It's in $\displaystyle{\mathbb{R}^2}$. So, which is the formula for the integral that we use?? At the proof, do we not use the fact that $u$ achieves its maximum also at $\partial{D}$??

Comment: I apologise, the integral should be over the whole ball, rather than just the boundary.

Comment: but the maximum is assumed to be the maximum over $\overline{U}$

Comment: I'm confused right now... Isn't the integral of the mean value only over the boundary, so only at the circle??

Comment: You can either integrate over the boundary and divide by $2\pi a$, or you can integrate over the whole sphere and divide by $\pi a^2$

Comment: Ahaa..Ok! And which is the formula of the integral over the boundary??

Comment: the one above i.e. $\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}u(r)dS$

Comment: And to what equals this integral??

Comment: the integral over the boundary :)

Comment: Yes, but I mean how can I calculate it????

Comment: if you knew what $u$ was, parametrise in polar coordinates, so in $\Bbb R^2$, $u(x,y)=u(r,\theta)$, on the boundary, $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ and $r=a$, you calculate the integral from $0$ to $2\pi$.
But in this proof there is no need to explicitly calculate the integral.

Comment: Ahaa...Does this integral equal to the length of circumference of the circle??

Comment: the entire integral $\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}u(r)dS$, gives the mean integral of $u$ over the boundary (or in this case ($\Bbb R^2$) the circumference).

Comment: So, $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|r|=a}{u(r)}dS=\frac{1}{2 \pi a} (2 \pi a)=1}$. Is this correct??

Comment: I see the confusion, it is true that $\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}1dS=1$, because it is a mean integral, and for a HARMONIC function $\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}u(y)dS=u(x)$. But in general things may not be so nice, but in the case of the maximum principle, $M$ is the maximum of $u$, so we have $u\le M$, thus $\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}u(y)dS\le\frac{1}{2\pi a}\int_{|r|=a}MdS=M$

Comment: But to say that $$\frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}|=a}u(\overrightarrow{r}) ds \leq \frac{1}{2 \pi a} \int_{|\overrightarrow{r}|=a} Mds$$
don't we have to know that $M$ is also the maximum of the points of the boundary of the circle??

Comment: yes $M$ is the maximum over the boundary also, since the theorem states the maximum is the maximum over $\overline{D}$, which includes the boundary

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)